# sudo freshclam not working: ERROR: Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!)

Tags: permissions, clamav

If I comment out the UpdateLogFile line from `/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf` like so...

```
\#UpdateLogFile /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

...then I am able to run sudo freshclam no problem:

```
/etc/clamav$ sudo freshclam ClamAV update process started at Mon Feb 
6 00:17:07 2017 main.cvd is up to date (version: 57, sigs: 4218790,
f-level: 60, builder: amishhammer) daily.cld is up to date (version:
23009, sigs: 1509149, f-level: 63, builder: neo) bytecode.cld is up to
date (version: 290, sigs: 55, f-level: 63, builder: neo)
```

However, if I uncomment the UpdateLogFile line in freshclam.conf and run sudo freshclam, I get this:

```
/etc/clamav$ sudo freshclam 
ERROR: Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

Here are the permissions on `/var/log`:

```
drwxrwxrwx  1 root root     9 Feb  3  2016 log
```

Here are the permissions on `/var/log/clamav`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 clamav    clamav    4096 Feb  5 22:18 clamav
```

And here are the permissions on `/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log`:

```
-rw-r-----  1 clamav adm       0 Feb  5 22:18 freshclam.log
```

I spent all day trying solutions mentioned in various forums with no luck.

Here is the version of Ubuntu server I am running:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
```

And the engine version of clamav:

```
Engine version: 0.99.2
```

Could someone help me?

Stopping the clamav-daemon does not help:

```
/var/log$ sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-daemon stop 

* Stopping ClamAV daemon clamd        
[ OK ]  /var/log$ sudo freshclam
ERROR: Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check
permissions!). ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile =
/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
```

The output of `sudo lsof | grep clam` is nothing:

```
/var/log$ sudo lsof | grep clam
/var/log$
```

It appears that nothing has a lock on `/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log`

Here is the output of `sudo service --status-all | grep clamav`, not including the lines that had question marks and were unrelated to clamav:

```
$ sudo service --status-all | grep clamav 
[ - ] clamav-daemon
[ - ] clamav-freshclam
$
```

Same `Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!)` error when I try to run clamav-daemon:

```
$ sudo service clamav-daemon start
 * Starting ClamAV daemon clamd
ERROR: Can't open /var/log/clamav/clamav.log in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Can't initialize the internal logger
$
```

**UPDATE:** purging and reinstalling `clamav`, `clamav-freshclam` and `clamav-daemon` did not resolve the issue. I still get the same error:

```
$ sudo freshclam
ERROR: Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!).
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
$
```

**UPDATE 2:** I did a `sudo reboot`, stopped `clamav-freshclam`, made sure `sudo lsof | grep clam` returned nothing and that the output of `sudo service --status-all | grep clamav` still only had minus symbols next to `clamav` and `clamav-daemon`. Ran `sudo freshclam` again, and same error as above (again).

Comment: My clam has the same permission with yours and the only thing I see when I try `sudo freshclam` is the `log file` is __locked__ by the `clamav daemon` so I know `clamav` is working, this append issue with your is what I trying to understand.

Comment: Hi George. When I run sudo lsof | grep /var/log/clamav/clamav.log, I do not see a line for /var/log/clamav/clamav.log, no. Regarding clamav-daemon, it appears to be installed based on the output of apt list --installed | grep clamav:

clamav-daemon/trusty-updates,trusty-security,now 0.99.2+addedllvm-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 amd64 [installed]

Comment: Please show me the result of `cat /etc/passwd | grep clamav`

Comment: Please do four things: 1) Comment out the line in the `/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf`, 2) restart your system, 3) run `sudo tail -f /var/log/clamav/clamav.log`, 4) run `sudo tail -f /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log` Please paste the results

Comment: Also please post the complete content of the `/etc/clamav/freshclam.conf`

Comment: Run this `sudo lsof -c freshclam` when comment is remove and when in place and compare the two results watch for the `freashclam.log` files in both results.

Comment: I am still waiting on your response!

Comment: I thin I believe I have figured it out _ping_ me when you see this message!

Answer (score 19):

`sudo freshclam` command is used for updating your antivirus database, which cannot be run while another instance (auto update)  is already running.

Stop auto uptade process:
`sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop`

Run manual update: `sudo freshclam`

Re-Start auto update process: `sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam start`

[source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1032147).

Comment: Hi Sirajus. Thanks for the response; however, running sudo freshclam is clearly not the problem in and of itself, since I can run sudo freshclam just fine as long as the UpdateLogFile line is commented out in /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf. The problem is with writing to /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log. I assume it's a permissions issue, I'm just not sure what the solution is. Your suggestion did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue as well and all that I really needed to do was set permissions on the log file :

```
chown -R clamav:adm /var/log/clamav/
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, I couldn't find the `/var/log/clamav/` directory so I simply created it:

```
mkdir /var/log/clamav/
```

and changed ownership:

```
chown -R clamav:clamav /var/log/clamav/
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at this [article](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/problem-with-internal-logger-clamav.496331/), and at my own `clamav` installation and would like to profer a solution.

Like you *error message* shows it's a *permission* problem and so try these solutions in sequence, I believe one should work:

**Option 1**

1. Checking `adm` group members and adding $USERNAME to it:

   ```
    cat /etc/group | grep ^adm

    # Result should be some thing similar to this:
    adm:x:4:syslog,george
   ```

   - where *syslog*: generates a log message, which will be distributed by syslogd, and *george*: user or owner of the system
2. If members of the `adm` don't include you or syslod add:

   ```
    sudo usermod -a -G adm syslog, and or
    sudo usermod -a -G adm $USERNAME
   ```
3. Restart the system and check if `freshclam` is working.

**Option 2**

1. Change the ownership of these files:

   ```
    /var/log/clamav/clamav.log
    /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log

    sudo chgrp $USERNAME /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
    sudo chgrp $USERNAME /var/log/clamav/clamav.log
   ```
2. Restart our system and check if `freshclam` is working

Source(s):

- man syslog
- https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/problem-with-internal-logger-clamav.496331/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just changed the `updatelogfile` line in `freshclam.conf` to `/var/log/clamav`.

The `freshclam.conf` is located in `/usr/local/etc/freshclam.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I used the command `sudo freshclam` and it kept timing out. However, I was able to download [the main database](https://database.clamav.net/main.cvd)

The download file is called main.cvd and is 112.4 Mb.  There is a 178.4 Mb file in `/var/lib/clamav/daily.cld` and it is timestamped with today's date.

It seems I'm up to date anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions, permissions!

Sometimes the error message does not always point to the actual cause of the problem.  Yes the ownership and permissions on the files and directories need to be correct (viz owned by clamav and writeable by the user clamav) but if you happen to be running apparmor you must also ensure that the apparmor profile usr.bin.freshclam in /etc/apparmor.d contains

```
          /var/lib/clamav/**     krw,
          /var/log/clamav/**     krw,
```

(the lib entry is the directory where the clamav database is created, and log entry is for the log files) or you will still get the permission denied message

```
   Can't open /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log in append mode (check permissions!).
```

(Similar arrangement apply for those who are using selinux instead of apparmor, but this is unlikely for most Ubuntu users.)

Answer (score 0):

Execute `ps -ef | grep clam` and you might see that freshclam is already run as a daemon for you so, I guess you don't need to run it manually. But if you really want to run it you can execute: `sudo -u clamav freshclam`.

```
$ps -ef | grep clam
clamav   2134306       1  1 10:57 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/freshclam -d --foreground=true
```